# Check if is a valid URL that ends in .jpg, .png, or .gif in wordpress post content

Tags: regex, wordpress, image, validation, url

I'm doing a front end form to let users submit a URL that is valid but also is an image, ending with .jpg, .png, or .gif.

This is my form:

```
<form action="" id="primaryPostForm" method="POST">

    <fieldset>
<p>Accepting GIF/JPG/PNG URL (Max size: 3MB)</p>
        <label for="postTitle"><?php _e('* POST TITLE:', 'framework') ?></label>

        <input type="text" name="postTitle" id="postTitle" class="required" value="<?php if ( isset( $_POST['postTitle'] ) ) echo $_POST['postTitle']; ?>" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <label for="postContent"><?php _e('* URL:', 'framework') ?></label>

        <textarea name="postContent" id="postContent" class="required" <?php if ( isset( $_POST['postContent'] ) ) { if ( function_exists( 'stripslashes' ) ) { echo stripslashes( $_POST['postContent'] ); } else { echo $_POST['postContent']; } } ?>></textarea>
    </fieldset>

<fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" /> 
        <button type="submit"><?php _e('SUBMIT', 'framework') ?></button>
    </fieldset>


</form>
```

This is how i get the INFO and create the post :

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) && isset( $_POST['post_nonce_field'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce' ) ) {

    $post_information = array(
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['postTitle'] ),
        'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
$new_post = wp_insert_post( $post_information );
```

I would like to check if characters inserted in the post_content match a URL that ends in .jpg/png/gif and from that point create a conditional tag like this :

if $_POST['postContent'] == URL THAT ENDS in JPG/PNG/GIF {
do something }

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried? There is plenty of example to verify URL (regex) and it is pretty simple to compare string ends.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic match for a URL along with your jpg/png/gif option at the end:

`\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]\.(?:jpg|png|gif)\b`

This rings alarm bells in my mind though, it could potentially be a security risk, if someone wanted to inject some kind of code into this form, they might be able to.

Hopefully your code can tell the difference between an image and a script.